# WSO2 Datamapper file resoure link missing

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2. I was trying out with WSO2 datamapper .

From input/output canvas, I clicked on load input option , I got prompted with sub window , but without load file link , load resource from file option is missing .

Please see screen shot below . Can someone let me know is it bug or i am doing something wrong . I am using studio version 7.0.2

[image]

Thanks
Brijesh

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with WSO2 Integration Studio 7.0.2 for high display resolutions(https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-ei/issues/851). You can remove the "-Dswt.autoScale=100" entry from the IntegrationStudio.ini file and restart the integration studio. Also, update the Integration Studio(Help->Check for Updates) after removing the entry from the .ini file.

Comment: I tried this option, but i am unable to drag the palletes .   if i edit from source ,  and open it in canvas window , editor remove the modified code from source . :-( , sort of blocker now.

Comment: Can you please try to get update (Help->Check for Updates)now and see? Update was hosted yesturday

Comment: as mentioned  , i did updates. Still unable to get file open link in data mapper

Comment: You should anyway remove the  "-Dswt.autoScale=100" from the integrationStudio.ini file. The update will fix the drag and drop issue